# mysqlx reported: failed at ssl configuration

Tags: mysql, ssl, mysql8

I have MySQL 8 with the `mysqlx` plugin enabled running on a standalone server that will never allow access to `3306` from outside the instance and have no worries about security within the instance.

I do not want the overhead of SSL connections for clients accessing either the standard or X interfaces.

I have disabled SSL in the `my.cnf` using the `skip_ssl` flag, however I'm now seeing in my logs a warning coming from the `mysqlx` plugin after a restart stating...

```
[Warning] [MY-011302] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Failed at SSL configuration: "SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key"'
```

I understand this is just a warning but is there no way to silence this message by specifically disabling SSL for the `mysqlx` plugin?  Or some other way?